# Java object compareto

Tags: java, compare, abstract, compareto

```
private Comparable[] items = new Comparable[1000000];   

bubbleSort(items);

public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void bubbleSort(T[] list){

    T temp;
    for (int k = 1; k < list.length; k++) {
    // Perform the kth pass
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length - k; i++) {
            if (list[i].compareTo(list[i + 1]) > 0){
                temp = list[i];
                list[i] = list[i + 1];
                list[i + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is with `if (list[i].compareTo(list[i]) > 0)`. I've commented everything out, one line at a time. That is the only thing that causes the error, and it doesn't give me any explanation in the output. Just which lines it is. which would be at the if, and calling the bubbleSort method.

Comment: A well behaved comparable should always have `list[i].compareTo(list[i]) == 0`. By definition. Did you mean `list[i].compareTo(list[k])` or vice versa?

Comment: it was actually supposed to say `list[i].compareTo(list[i + 1])` I fixed it in the original post.

Comment: And that is still causing a problem? What is the error?

Comment: It says "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: @ChrisVachon What error have you got? A NullPointerException maybe?

Comment: Thats the one NullPointer

Comment: @ChrisVachon it means that your array contains null elements. How do you populate it?

Comment: @assylias I was only filling it to 50,000 items. I was just using the wrong array. Thank you though, I wouldn't have figured it out myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Comparable[] items = new Comparable[1000000];
```

This line does not initialize any element in the array. You have `null` in every slot, hence your `NullPointerException`.

Or maybe you just didn't post init code, but then the problem would be there.